# Why is it logging "Reference Error" in the first case, why didn't it pick it from the global scope like in the second case?

Tags: javascript, function, keyword, scoping

Why is it logging **"Reference Error"** in the first case, why didn't it pick it from the global scope like in the second case?

```js
let a = 10;

function test1() {
  console.log(a);
  let a = 100;
}

test1(); // Reference Error
```

```js
let a = 10;

function test2() {
  console.log(a);
}

test2(); //10
```

Comment: You're missing the important part of the error message: _"...can't access lexical declaration 'a' before initialization"_

Comment: @andreas  , Can you please elaborate?

Comment: I've mentioned the relevant part in my comment: _"...can't access lexial declaration..."_. It's also explained in detail in the two dupe targets at the top of your question.